# product of polynomials in $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ where $K$ is a field.

Tags: polynomials

Let
\begin{align*}
\Phi_\sigma :E&\longrightarrow E,\\
p(X_1,...,X_n)&\longmapsto p(X_{\sigma (1)},...,X_{\sigma (n)}),
\end{align*}
where $\sigma \in\mathfrak S_n$.

I would like to show that $$\Phi_\sigma (p(X_1,...,X_n)q(X_1,...,X_n))=\Phi_\sigma (p(X_1,...,X_n))\Phi_\sigma (q(X_1,...,X_n)),$$
can I do by induction ? My idea is:

For $n=1$ its obvious. We suppose the property true for $n-1$, therefore,

$$\Phi_\sigma \Big(p(X_1,...,X_n)q(X_1,...,X_n)\Big)=\Phi_\sigma \Big(p(X_1,...,X_{n-1})(X_n)q(X_1,...X_{n-1})(X_n)\Big)=\Phi_\sigma (\tilde p(X_n)\tilde q(X_n))=\Phi_\sigma \Big(\sum_{i}\sum_{j}a_i b_j X_n^{i+j}\Big)=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}a_{i}b_jX_{\sigma (n)}^{i+j}=\tilde p(X_{\sigma (n)})\tilde q(X_{\sigma (n)})=\Phi_\sigma (\tilde p(X_n))\Phi_\sigma (\tilde q(X_n)),$$

where $a_i$ are the coefficient of $\tilde p$, $b_j$ the coefficient of $\tilde q$, $\tilde p(X_n)=p(X_1,...,X_{n-1})(X_n)$ and $\tilde q(X_n)=q(X_1,...,X_{n-1},X_n).$

Do you think it work ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the coefficients $a_i,b_j$ in your proof depends on $X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}$ and it is not clear in your proof how they changes when you permute the indexes. Here are some other directions:

- You can prove it by induction over the number of monomials appearing in $p$ (use $\Phi\big(p(X)+q(X)\big) = \Phi\big(p(X)\big)+\Phi\big(q(X)\big)$).
- You can check it directly (probably shorter). Write $$ p(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \sum_{j_1\in [d],\ldots,j_n \in [d]} p_{j_1,\ldots,j_n} X_1^{j_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot X_n^{j_n}$$
  with $d$ the the degree of $p$, $[d]:=\{1,\ldots,d\}$ and $p_{j_1,\ldots,j_n}\in K$ for every $j_1,\ldots,j_n\in [d]$. Write $q$ on the same form and use $\big(\sum_{l\in [m_1]} \alpha_l\big)\big(\sum_{k\in [m_2]} \beta_k\big) = \sum_{l\in [m_1],k\in [m_2]}\alpha_l\beta_k$.